# Заморозка переменной через time.sleep() не работает

Tags: python, функции, время

Форумчане, вечер добрый, есть функция `shoot`, цикл которой должен засыпать на время, но при добавлении `time.sleep()` весь код перестает работать.

```
def shoot():
    global by
    while by > -20:
        by-=5
        screen.blit(bulletimage, (bx+21, by))
    by = 550
```

Вот весь код:

```
import pygame as pg
import time

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((600,700))

FPS = 60
clock = pg.time.Clock()

ex = 0
enmoveside = 'right'
bx = 0
by = 550
px = 250

#Загрузка спрайтов
bulletimage = pg.image.load('bullet.png')
shipimage = pg.image.load('angryship.png')
friendlyshipimg = pg.image.load('friendlyship.png')
bgimg = pg.image.load('bg_cosmo.png')

#Функция выстрела
def shoot():
    global by
    while by > -20:
        by-=5
        screen.blit(bulletimage, (bx+21, by))
    by = 550

        
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            pg.quit()
            quit
    
    #отрисовка бэкграунда
    screen.blit(bgimg, (0, 0))
    
    #Проверка нажатия мыши и запуск функции выстрела
    mpressed = pg.mouse.get_pressed()
    if mpressed[0]:
        bx = px
        shoot()

    #отрисовка спрайтов    
    screen.blit(shipimage, (ex,250))
    screen.blit(friendlyshipimg, (px,550))

    #movement
    key = pg.key.get_pressed()
    if key[pg.K_a]:
        px -= 5
    if key[pg.K_d]:
        px += 5

    #barriers
    if px < 0:
        px = 0
    if px > 500:
        px = 500
    
    
    #enemy move
    if enmoveside == 'right':
        ex += 2
        if ex > 500:
            enmoveside = 'left'
    else:
        ex -= 2
        if ex < 0:
            enmoveside = 'right'

    clock.tick(FPS)
    pg.display.update()
```

Comment: Ну вроде всё логично, в этом и есть смысл time.sleep — останавливать работу кода на указанное время

Comment: А как мне остановить саму функцию?

Comment: Если time.sleep останавливает весь код, то вполне логично, что он остановит в том числе и ту функцию, в которой он находится

Comment: Мне нужно установить задержку выполнения цикла в функции, чтобы при этом весь код работал.

Comment: Что такое «весь код» и какое отношение он имеет к функции?

Comment: Внёс правки в вопрос, щас переписываю под ООП, но функции все равно нужно задержку сделать, как это реализовать?

Comment: А как мне это сделать?

Comment: Используйте pygame.time.set_timer()

Answer (score 0):

В чем заключается вопрос? Если вы про то - почему код зависает, то все логично. Игра - бесконечный цикл в котором бесконечно повторяются функции. Засовываешь в функцию `time.sleep` - останавливаешь весь код, ведь цикл бесконечно пока истинно True будет выполнять эту функцию и слипать цикл, т.е саму игру на 1 секунду.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import time

start = time.time()

def shoot():
    end = time.time() - start
    if end >= 1:
        global by
        while by > -20:
            by-=5
            screen.blit(bulletimage, (bx+21, by))
        by = 550
        start = time.time()
```

Comment: вначале создай переменную start, потом в функции проверяется сколько времени прошло с момента начала работы или конца последней активации функции, потом смотрит, что прошла ли 1 секунда или нет, если да, то выполняется код в if и обновляется таймер.

Comment: Всё равно не работает, на экране ничего не происходит, но оно хотя бы и не зависает)

Answer (score -2):

1. импортируйте модуль time
2. `time.sleep(t)`

   t — это количество секунд, на которое выполнение должно быть приостановлено(в
   секундах). Если Вы не укажите t, то вылезет, вроде, ошибка `TypeError: time.sleep() takes exactly one argument (0 given)`

Comment: Нет, при указывании t, зависает всё окно.

Comment: А куда Вы его именно добавляете и на сколько t ставите?

Comment: добавляю в конец цикла в функции shoot, t ставлю на 1

Comment: Да, сюда добавляю после screen.blit, time.sleep(1)